# android build fails with error - null is not an object

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a private gitlab repo (react native module) and i added this repo to my App's package.json.

index file in my private gitlab repo:

[image]

ios methods:

[image]

android methods:

[image]

Now in my App, i install the above module and i call the methods.

App's package.json
[image]

App.js

[image]

In ios, everything works perfectly fine.
Both "multiply" **(HealthLibrary.multiply()]** and "requestAuthorization" **[HealthLibrary.requestAuthorization()]** work fine.

But when i run "react-native run-android", the build is successful but the display is a blank screen with this error in the log

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'nativeModule.requestAuthorization')
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Why does this error pop up only when i run android??i am not even calling "requestAuthorization" method yet i am unable to build the app in Android.
Any help would be great guys....

Comment: Properly formatted code snippets are preferred over images of code. Text is easer to read and more importantly, is searchable.

Answer (score 0):

In the images you have provided, there seems to be no `requestAuthorization` method in your android file, only a method called 'getAuthorization'.

Comment: exactly. yet I get this error. Any idea why?

Comment: If in your js code you are calling a `requestAuthorization` method, it must exist in the native modules your are exposing, and in case of the Java module, it seems that you have a `getAuthorization` method but no `requestAuthorization` method, this is what the error message is hinting at.